# How do I check my SqlConnection state before open connection?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqlconnection

How can I check if connection is already open with `mysqlconnection`?. I want that if connection is already open then not need to open it again:

```
 Connection = New MySqlConnection()
 Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DbConncetionString").ConnectionString
 Connection.Open()
 SQL = "SELECT * from TBL_PARKERS where id=" & encode(Request.Cookies("parker").Values("id")) & ""
 Dim Query As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(SQL, Connection)
 'Here  i want to check connection is open or close 
 Connection.Open()
```

Comment: Is there anything bad that could happen if you open it twice? If "no", then don't bother.

Answer (score 3):

Given `MySqlConnection` derives from [DbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can check the [State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.state%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property e.g.

```
Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for test connection.

Public Function TestConn(ByVal server As String) As Boolean

```
    Using tcpSocket As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        Try
            Dim async As IAsyncResult = tcpSocket.BeginConnect(server, 1433, Nothing, Nothing)
            Dim startTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now

            Do
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                If (async.IsCompleted) Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop While (DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds < 5)

            If (async.IsCompleted) Then
                tcpSocket.EndConnect(async)
                Return True
            End If
            tcpSocket.Close()

            If (async.IsCompleted = False) Then
                Return False
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            My.Application.Log.WriteEntry("[" & DateTime.Now & "] - " & ex.Source & ": " & ex.Message)


        End Try
    End Using
End Function
```

Remember open TCP/IP port number 1433.

Regards!